# Python 3 using many cores for a single threaded script

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am using a simple python 3 script which I wrote to parse through some very large files. It is a single threaded script (I don't even know how to set up a multithreading python script).

HOWEVER, this script is using 30+ cores on our computer cluster when I run the script.

The script only uses the argparse module and another module called pyBigWig. How can this be using 30 cores???

---- EDIT ----

I can't say that I'm surprised to instantly receive downvotes, despite this being a real issue that I'm facing and trying my best to describe the problem.

The entire script depends on this simple loop where I go through each line of the file:

```
with open(file, 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
    # assign some variables from this line
    # calculate some values from these variables
    # write new values to a new line of a new output file
```

Comment: Are you sure all are used at the same time and the process isn't just "hopping" from core to core?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Yes I can see using `top` that it is using ~3200% CPU usage for a long period.

Comment: pyBigWig is a C extension, probably it is doing a lot of heavy processing and has multiple threads under the hood

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn I think you must be right. Do you know of any way I could limit the cores used by a python module?

Comment: For UNIX-like OS there is the `taskset` utility.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `numpy` module was using all the cores. I have managed to limit this by adding this to the top of my script:

```
import os
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" 
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1"
```